# Read file contents into batch variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables, iteration

Good afternoon:

I have a text file full of usernames, one per row -

```
name1
name2
name3
etc...
```

I'm trying to get a batch file to read each line into `dsmod` so I can set each username to `mustchpwd yes`.  I've read a bunch of things about this but can't quite get it to work.  Looking for something like -

```
set things=usernames.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%things%) do "dsmod user 
cn=%things%,ou=yea,dc=yea,dc=yea,dc=yea -mustchpwd yes"
```

I know that's not correct, but hopefully it gets the point across.  I feel like this is something that should be pretty simple...I'm a batch-n00b though.

So...if anyone can help me out real quick, I'd appreciate it!

Thank you!!

Comment: Change the `cn=%things%` to `cn=%%i` and remove the opening and closing double quotes on your dsmod command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like that :

```bat
@echo off
set things=usernames.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%things%) do (
    echo "dsmod user cn=%%i,ou=yea,dc=yea,dc=yea,dc=yea -mustchpwd yes"
)
pause
```

After checking this code; You can remove the `echo` command before your main `dsmod` command

Comment: You are the man.  (...or woman...)

Had to remove the quotes around the dsmod command when I removed the echo, but other than that...perfect.  Thank you!